# extract time from date Vertica

Tags: database, vertica

How to Extract time from a date in vertica ..for example we can use

```
select cast(AttDate as time) [time]
from yourtable
```

in sql..is there any similar functions available in vertica database ?

Comment: -1 What does 'in sql' mean? What platform? What is the actual output you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try,

```
select to_char(getdate(), 'HH:MI:SS AM');
```

for more infomation please refer
[Link](http://www.vertica-forums.com/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=366)

Answer (score 0):

You can CAST to TIME in Vertica too:

```
dbadmin=> SELECT sysdate, CAST(sysdate AS TIME) just_time FROM dual;
          sysdate           |    just_time
----------------------------+-----------------
 2018-04-16 09:43:25.635428 | 09:43:25.635428
(1 row)
```